# Populating a dict with for loop from a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

Hello I have the following list :

```py
Info_Types = [
    {'name': 'A'},
    {'name': 'B'},
    {'name': 'C'}
    ]
```

Next, I would like to use this list with a loop in this type of dictionary:

```py
{
    "name": Info_Types[i]['name'],
    "domainId": "c50d7ff8-0e6d-4132-a528-f286781f017b",
    "typeId": "1bf1b4ac-f52f-4ff9-be43-f96d76dff4c1",
    "statusId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005008",
    "excludedFromAutoHyperlinking": 'true'
}
```

The result I want to get is the following:

```py
      [{'name': 'A',
     'domainId': 'c50d7ff8-0e6d-4132-a528-f286781f017b',
     'typeId': '1bf1b4ac-f52f-4ff9-be43-f96d76dff4c1',
     'statusId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005008',
     'excludedFromAutoHyperlinking': 'true'},
      {'name': 'B',
     'domainId': 'c50d7ff8-0e6d-4132-a528-f286781f017b',
     'typeId': '1bf1b4ac-f52f-4ff9-be43-f96d76dff4c1',
     'statusId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005008',
     'excludedFromAutoHyperlinking': 'true'},
     {'name': 'C',
     'domainId': 'c50d7ff8-0e6d-4132-a528-f286781f017b',
     'typeId': '1bf1b4ac-f52f-4ff9-be43-f96d76dff4c1',
     'statusId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005008',
     'excludedFromAutoHyperlinking': 'true'}]
```

My idea is that I need to use a for loop but I don't really know how to build it. Someone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use list comprehension:

```py
result = [
    {
        "name": name,
        "domainId": "c50d7ff8-0e6d-4132-a528-f286781f017b",
        "typeId": "1bf1b4ac-f52f-4ff9-be43-f96d76dff4c1",
        "statusId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000005008",
        "excludedFromAutoHyperlinking": 'true'
    }
    for name in Info_Types
]
```